# How to start Vimba API as ubuntu service

Tags: ubuntu, service, camera, alliedvision, vimba-sdk

I'm having an issue with ubuntu service that includes Vimba API which is about the Allied Vision Cameras.
the application that i built includes Vimba API, tcp/ip server and rs485 communication. It is going to be used in closed loop system so i have to write an ubuntu service.
first of all i created a script that runs the application.
The script im using is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
user="$(whoami)"
if [ X"$(uname -m)" = X"x86_64" ]
then
    arch="x86_64"
elif [ X"$(uname -m)" = X"aarch64" ]
then
    arch="arm_64"   
fi

echo $user
echo $arch

/home/${user}/Desktop/App/App_Scripts/bin/${arch}bit/changeName jetson1
/home/${user}/Desktop/App/App_Scripts/App.sh
```

The service im using is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=App Service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=6
User=jetson1
ExecStart=/home/Desktop/App/App_Scripts/App.sh/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i run the App.sh with my bare hands as a standard user it works but when i start the app service it gives me No Transport Layer error.

i tried to add the necessary libraries or dependencies to the ubuntu service.
i changed the script owner and group and also add sudo at the beginning of the command.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things may help:

1. Can you run the script as sudo -E? (-E saves environment variables)
2. Add one of these to your .bashrc file:

## 32-bit

export GENICAM_GENTL32_PATH=$GENICAM_GENTL32_PATH:"/opt/Vimba_6_0/VimbaGigETL/CTI/x86_32bit/"

## 64-bit

export GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH=$GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH:"/opt/Vimba_6_0/VimbaGigETL/CTI/x86_64bit/"

Then type source .bashrc to make sure the path is created in your environment variables.

Comment: When i run the script as sudo -E it worked. then i had to change my service. i add 'Environment' to the '[Service]' section like this
`Environment=GENICAM_GENTL64_PATH=:/AppVimbaUSBTL/arm_64bit/CTI/arm_64bit`
so basically sudo -e solved my problem